# How to get User and the User Role information in one query?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a model like below

```
public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string? Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Key]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual UserRole Role { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Role")]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
    }

public class UserRole
    {
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RoleName {  get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to get list of all users with RoleName. I tried the below, but its not working. Can someone please help me

```
var user = context.UserModel
                    .Include(x => x.Role.Select(x => x.RoleName)
                    .AsNoTracking()
```

Expected output format

```
[
  {
    "userID": 0,
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "roleName": "string",
    "roleID": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
var user = context.UserModel
                    .Select(x => new UserModel
                    {
                        UserId = x.UserID,
                        FirstName = x.FirstName,
                        LastName = x.LastName,
                        Phone = x.Phone,
                        Email = x.Email,
                        RoleName = x.Role.RoleName,
                        RoleID = x.Role.RoleID,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Remove `Include` and answer should be fine.

Comment: It says User does not contain the RoleName, should i have RoleName property as well in my User Model?

Comment: i added a [NotMapped] public string RoleName { get; set; } and it works.. hope this is fine

Comment: Hope I helped you